# Single Oracle SQL query with CTE produces "SELECT list inconsistent with GROUP BY" error

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, common-table-expression

I've got an Oracle query (unfortunately, I don't know DBMS version) that needs to return only one row of data. Also, it needs to be a single SELECT query, so temporary tables and parameters declarations are not allowed.

First, I'm using a CTE which aggregates values on all columns except the first, which is used as a GROUP BY condition. I need to display all those values in a single row, which works (I'm using 3 CROSS JOINs on filtered CTE, joining three one-row datasets, resulting in also a one-row dataset).

If I run only the CTE (not the whole CTE, just the SELECT in it), it works and produces no error. But if I wrap this SELECT statement in WITH ... AS construct, I'm given the error - Oracle SQL Developer.

Here is the CTE:

```
WITH
FRUITDATASET AS (
    SELECT
        -- FROM HERE, ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER MARKS LINES AS ERRONEOUS
        FRUITTYPE,
        COUNT(LONDONFRESH) AS LONDONFRESH,
        COUNT(BERLINFRESH) AS BERLINFRESH,
        SUM(0) AS LONDONSTALE,
        SUM(0) AS BERLINSTALE
        -- FROM HERE, THE QUERY IS VALID AGAIN
    FROM
        [...]
    GROUP BY
        FRUITTYPE

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        -- FROM HERE, THE ERROR HAPPENS AGAIN
        FRUITTYPE,
        SUM(0) AS LONDONFRESH,
        SUM(0) AS BERLINFRESH,
        COUNT(LONDONSTALE) AS LONDONSTALE,
        COUNT(BERLINSTALE) AS BERLINSTALE
        -- FROM HERE IT'S OKAY
    FROM
        [...]
    GROUP BY
        FRUITTYPE
)
```

Here is how I use the CTE:

```
SELECT
    SUM(APPLES.LONDONFRESH) AS LONDONFRESHAPPLES,
    SUM(APPLES.BERLINFRESH) AS BERLINFRESHAPPLES,
    SUM(APPLES.LONDONSTALE) AS LONDONSTALEAPPLES,
    SUM(APPLES.BERLINSTALE) AS BERLINSTALEAPPLES,
    SUM(GRAPES.LONDONFRESH) AS LONDONFRESHGRAPES,
    SUM(GRAPES.BERLINFRESH) AS BERLINFRESHGRAPES,
    SUM(GRAPES.LONDONSTALE) AS LONDONSTALEGRAPES,
    SUM(GRAPES.BERLINSTALE) AS BERLINSTALEGRAPES
FROM
    DUAL

    CROSS JOIN FRUITDATASET APPLES
    ON APPLES.FRUITTYPE = 'APPLE'

    CROSS JOIN FRUITDATASET GRAPES
    ON GRAPES.FRUITTYPE = 'GRAPE'
```

Query runs anyway when I run it from SQL Developer, but if I put it into a report, it throws an exception. I've tried putting

```
NULL AS LONDONFRESH
[...]
GROUP BY
    FRUITTYPE,
    NULL
```

but it still doesn't work. Can you guys help me find out what's wrong with this query?

**EDIT:**
I think I probably solved this by using analytic functions:

```
WITH
FRUITDATASET AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT FRUITTYPE,
            COUNT(LONDONFRESH) OVER(PARTITION BY FRUITTYPE) AS LONDONFRESH,
            COUNT(BERLINFRESH) OVER(PARTITION BY FRUITTYPE) AS BERLINFRESH,
            SUM(NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY FRUITTYPE) AS LONDONSTALE,
            SUM(NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY FRUITTYPE) AS BERLINSTALE
        FROM
            [...]
    )

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        *
    FROM (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT FRUITTYPE,
            SUM(NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY FRUITTYPE) AS LONDONFRESH,
            SUM(NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY FRUITTYPE) AS BERLINFRESH,
            COUNT(LONDONSTALE) OVER(PARTITION BY FRUITTYPE) AS LONDONSTALE,
            COUNT(BERLINSTALE) OVER(PARTITION BY FRUITTYPE) AS BERLINSTALE
        FROM
            [...]
    )
)
```

Right now I'm unable to check this solution on the server, but I'll post an answer as soon as I find out.

Comment: What exception does it throw? Who throws the exception?

Comment: @SamuelRenold Report engine throws the ORA-00973 not a single-group group function java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently wrapping CTE into SELECT * FROM does the trick. Everything is working now.

Comment: Strange, but true